# 'I wouldn't lie' vs 'I wouldn't be lying'

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Is there any difference between those two forms:

- I wouldn't be lying
- I wouldn't lie

For example:

- I wouldn't be lying if I said this is the best evening in my life!
- I wouldn't lie if I said this is the best evening in my life!

Do both forms could be used interchangeably? Or second one sounds a bit unnatural?

Answer (score 1):

"Wouldn't lie" is a hypothetical about a future condition.  It doesn't refer to the thing you are currently speaking about, but something you might say in the future.

You might say

> I wouldn't lie if you ask me how you look tonight.

(He is speaking about a lie he would not make in the future)

But in the expression in the question, you are speaking about the words you are in the process of saying, and so the continuous form is correct.

> I wouldn't be lying if ...

So the two forms are rather different in meaning.

Comment: In your first example sentence, do you mean, "I wouldn't **lie** if you ask**ed** me..."?

Comment: ... shouldn't **ask** be backshifted in your first example?

Comment: Would can express a hypothetical in the present tense, so could be used with "ask", but "asked" might be more usual.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences are quite different. The second one has a very odd meaning.

"I wouldn't be lying if I said..." means "It is true that...", so the first sentence means, "*It is true that this is the best evening of my life!"*

On the other hand, "I wouldn't lie if [condition]" means "I might lie if the condition isn't met." In your example it means, "If I don't say ..., I might lie (after)." It means that saying the words "This is the best evening of my life!" somehow prevents you from telling lies, like it's a magical incantation.

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

> I wouldn't be lying if I said this is the best evening in my life!

is correct but overly expressive, like movie dialog.  'wouldn't be lying' keep the focus on the current statement.

> I wouldn't lie if I said this is the best evening in my life!

This just sounds weird, understandable but not quite right.  "I wouldn't lie" would be interpreted as a general statement about the speakers character.